# iPhone 5 app compatibility, Is it mandatory to change all the images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, iphone-5

I want to make my App compatible for iPhone 5, i got the point about auto resizing just need to confir, Do i need to add all the images re-sized for iPhone 5 OR can work with re-sizeing only Splash and Background image ?

Comment: I think you need to improve a little bit  accepted answer rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be required to resize the launch images. You need a launch image for the older iPhone screen sizes in normal and retina resolutions as well as an iPhone 5 screen size retina image.

It will be a good idea to rework your app and have background images that can take advantage of the larger iPhone 5 screen size, but will be able to be cropped and still work on the older iPhone screens.

Using either auto layout or setting the resize and pinning struts properly, your other controls and images should be able to be used as they are to adapt your app to look good on the iPhone 5 screen.

Comment: thanks jeff ya i tried this and its working fine. one more thing will apple approve this if we do not resize all the controls, just resize the frames of other controls according to screen size?

Comment: Apple should approve your app if you only make minimal adjustments to have all the appropriate launch images, have backgrounds fill the 4" screen size and have any `UIScrollView`, `UITableView` or similarly resizable content views automatically resize vertically using the options in the size inspector. Please be sure to check the green arrow to the left to accept the answer as your accepted solution if this information was helpful.

Comment: ok thanks jeff will apply this i hope my app should get approved.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to resize the splash screen.